# upgrading from precise to trusty

Tags: upgrade

I have an old laptop running ubuntu 12.04 precise and i wanted to upgrade it to ubuntu 14.04 trusty. I have seen many methods such as do-dist-upgrade etc. But I wanted to ask if it is enough to just replace the source.list file from precise to trusty and then do the update and upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

use this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes?_ga=1.236620673.1065164992.1468443213. This link can tell everything about upgrade process of ubuntu.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.